# How to save values from query in shared_preferences with conditional statement flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a query function for data from the database that comes with the id number from the database, then the id is saved in shared_preferences in case the new id that comes from the database is larger than the old id that was in the shared_preferences previously.But after running the code, the following problem comes:

```
E/flutter (30884): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'String' has no instance method '<'.
E/flutter (30884): Receiver: ""
E/flutter (30884): Tried calling: <(7)
E/flutter (30884): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
E/flutter (30884): #1      AddCommentsState.getLogin.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_apptestqeuriy/AddComment.dart:84:46)
E/flutter (30884): #2      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1240:30)
E/flutter (30884): #3      AddCommentsState.getLogin (package:flutter_apptestqeuriy/AddComment.dart:78:5)
E/flutter (30884): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (30884): #4      AddCommentsState.initState.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_apptestqeuriy/AddComment.dart:57:9)
E/flutter (30884): #5      interval.function (package:flutter_apptestqeuriy/AddComment.dart:21:9)
E/flutter (30884): #6      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1182:47)
E/flutter (30884): #7      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter (30884): #8      _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
E/flutter (30884): #9      _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
E/flutter (30884): #10     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
E/flutter (30884): #11     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter (30884): #12     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:23)
E/flutter (30884): #13     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:18:15)
E/flutter (30884): #14     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:397:19)
E/flutter (30884): #15     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:428:5)
E/flutter (30884): #16     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
E/flutter (30884):
```

This is the code used to query from the database:

```
  var user_id;
  var my_pre_id;

Future<String> getLogin() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull("http://xxxxxxxxxxx/Application.php"),);
    setState(() {
      var convertDataToJson = json.decode(response.body);
        data = convertDataToJson['result'];
      if (data != null) {
         user_id = int.parse(data[0]['id']);
         my_pre_id = _myPreferences.id;
         if (my_pre_id == null  || my_pre_id < user_id ){
           _myPreferences.id = user_id;
           _myPreferences.commit();
           //   print("tappeeeeedddd $my_pre_id");
         }
      }

    });
  }
```

Does anyone know the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue comes from `my_pre_id < user_id` where `my_pre_id` is actually a `String`. You might want to do an `int.parse()` on it as well or change its type in the class.